# Connecting user to another account (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc')

Tags: facebook, security, authentication, twitter, single-sign-on

I have a theoretical question regarding connecting users in my app I'm writing to another account like Facebook, Twitter etc'.
What would be better solution (in views of security, best practice, etc'):
1. Connect all accounts to one user and log in to it from
2. Do not allow connect users from different providers and create distinct user for every provider.

Meanwhile, I have an aspect of SSO - in the 1st option, SSO doesn't exist and user can log in from different providers and use different passwords for the same account (my app account). The same user can log in with a native password, or via Facebook up for example and provide me his access token for further authentication on the server side.

Would like to hear you opinions and suggestion and to raise new issues.

Comment: First option is less secure, but more handy for the user. So it's a matter of your choice which way to go.